# Make two tables in one line

Tags: python, python-docx

How can I make tables inline with `python-docx`. I searched lot of but could not find out that helpfully. I have two tables but they are all in vertical line. I want them to be horizantal. How can I do that?

**My tables are simple:**

```
table = document.add_table(rows=2, cols=2)
table2 = document.add_table(rows=2, cols=2)
```

Comment: How would you do that by hand in Word?